# C program creating pointer in loop results in memory leak

Tags: c, memory-leaks

I'm writing a C program (I'm new to C) that reads the number of lines in a file and then stores each line in an array, in a loop.

```
while(1){
    (...)
    int lines = file_lines(path_to_file);        // number of lines in the file
    char *contents[lines];                       // pointer creation
    read_file(contents, lines, path_to_file);    // read the contents of the file to the variable "contents"
    (...)
}
```

However, I noticed this piece of code is responsible for a huge memory leak (the memory increases by 1% every second until I can no longer use my computer).

I suppose the problem is that I'm constantly creating a new `char*` for contents. However, since the number of lines in the file may vary (I may edit it), I cannot declare that variable outside the while loop.

What could be a possible solution?

If it is useful, this is the `read_file` function, and I would prefer a solution that would not require to change it:

```
void read_file(char *contents[], int lines,  char *filename){
    int j = 0;
    size_t len = 0;

    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");

    for(j = 0; j < lines; j++){
        contents[j] = NULL;
        len = 0;
        getline(&contents[j], &len, file);
    }
    fclose(file);
}
```

Comment: `getline(&contents[j], &len, file);` allocates memory for you. So you have to free it at some point. If the file is very big, yes, you can freeze your computer.

Comment: it's not a memory leak if you need the data. Just free `contents[j]` pointers when you're done.

Comment: I didn't know getline allocated memory. The problem is fixed now!

Comment: Note that `getline()` usually allocates memory even on the iteration when it gets EOF (it allocates some space before attempting to read).  You should `free(contents[j]);` after the loop (e.g. before `fclose(file);`).  But that's a little leak rather than a big one.  Note too that if the lines in the file are, say, 32-64 bytes each, then you're wasting space — `getline()` is likely to allocate 256 bytes for each line.  You might do better using a single variable for a buffer, and then use `strdup()` to copy that into `contents[j]`.  You could be saving yourself 190 bytes per line or more.

Comment: That is: `char *buffer = 0; size_t len = 0; for(j = 0; j < lines; j++) { if (getline(&buffer, &len, file) == -1) break; contents[j] = strdup(buffer); } free(buffer); fclose(file);`.  That way, `getline()` reuses the `buffer` space and rarely allocates more; meanwhile, `contents` only contains pointers to suitably sized chunks of memory.

Comment: That seems like an even better ideia. I will modify my code accordingly.